# angular2 - just installed ng2-bootstrap. how do I use this package without manually including it within <script>?

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I am using angular 2 CLI for my application.

I installed ng2-bootstrap, and I am wondering how I can use the systemJS tool to automatically include that in my application instead of having to manually put in:

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Does this go into the system-config.ts?  If so, what do I have to do?  I tried putting ng2-bootstrap into the third party barrels section, but it didn't seem to do anything.

I ask because I see this in the index.html for the app:

```
{{#each scripts.polyfills}}
    <script src="{{.}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Thanks

my system-config.js

```
"use strict";

// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'ng2-bootstrap': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js'
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/browse',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

Comment: Yes, you need to configure ssytemjs. Post your systemjs config.

Comment: hey.  done.  i am following this btw - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-bootstrap-to-your-project

Comment: omg I figured it out.. spelling mistake... i hate my life right now... 3:30am lol